# Easiest way to make a button in Gamemaker Studio 2

Tags: game-maker-dnd

I want to make a menu for my title screen where the user can click on the option they want. The only way I can think of doing this is by making an object that checks if there is a click and then checks if the mouse is on top of it. This feels like a really round-about way to do this. Is there an easier way? I don't yet know how to use the GML so, please use DnD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use the Left Pressed event:**

[image]

This way the action will only be performed if there is a mouse click on the object (in this case the button). The click area will exactly match the size of the sprite.

**As a matter of curiosity/information:**

Since you want to know the simplest way to do this and not the most optimized/functional way, the image shows how to do what you want. This case specifically (clicking a button) is quite simple to convert to GML.